# Get string text from a group tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I want get string of content of a group tag xml

Exemple this xml:

```
<retEvento versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <infEvento>
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <verAplic>SVRSnfce201808211044</verAplic>
        <cOrgao>22</cOrgao>
        <cStat>135</cStat>
        <xMotivo>Evento registrado e vinculado a NF-e</xMotivo>
        <chNFe>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</chNFe>
        <tpEvento>110111</tpEvento>
        <nSeqEvento>1</nSeqEvento>
        <dhRegEvento>2019-04-17T15:59:45-03:00</dhRegEvento>
        <nProt>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</nProt>
    </infEvento>
</retEvento>
```

And i want get string content of infEvento group. Like this:

```
<infEvento>
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <verAplic>SVRSnfce201808211044</verAplic>
        <cOrgao>22</cOrgao>
        <cStat>135</cStat>
        <xMotivo>Evento registrado e vinculado a NF-e</xMotivo>
        <chNFe>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</chNFe>
        <tpEvento>110111</tpEvento>
        <nSeqEvento>1</nSeqEvento>
        <dhRegEvento>2019-04-17T15:59:45-03:00</dhRegEvento>
        <nProt>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</nProt>
    </infEvento>
```

I try this:

```
ns = {'ns':'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
el.xpath('//ns:retEvento',namespaces=ns)[0].text
```

but i get nothing :(

Comment: Which XML parser are you using?

Comment: i parse with lxml ex: from lxml import etree; etree.fromstring(Input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `tostring` method.

```
etree.tostring(el.xpath('//ns:retEvento',namespaces=ns)[0])
```

Comment: worker but i need access one level //ns:retEvento//ns:infEvento and i get the string. Finally code is etree.tostring(el.xpath('//ns:retEvento//ns:infEvento',namespaces=ns)[0])